# Can there be a holomorphic on a disc for which $f(z)=f(\alpha z)$ whereas $\alpha$ is transcendental?

Tags: complex-analysis, transcendental-numbers

Can there be a holomorphic on a disc for which $f(z)=f(\alpha z)$ whereas $\alpha$ is transcendental and $\alpha z \in D$? where D is the disc.
I believe it to be true as I find no reason for contradiction.
But I find no example.

Edit: it seems that the constant function does hold for this question with any transcendental $|\alpha|=1$. Is there a non constant function?

Comment: If $z\ne0$ then $z\ne \alpha z$, so $f$ cannot be injective if $f(z)=f(\alpha z)$

Comment: @leoli1 fixed the question.

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for just one $z$ or for all $z$ in $D$?

Comment: any z in f. @leoli1

Answer (score 1):

Choosing an holomorphic branch of $\log(z)$ then $f(z) =\exp(2i\pi \log(z)/\log(\alpha))$ works on any disk not containing $0$.

If the disk contains $0$ then write the power series of $f(z)$ and $f(\alpha z)$ and equate the coefficients.

Comment: so you claim that if 0 is included then there can't be?